# Function call from inside axios then?

Tags: reactjs, axios

How to call a function from inside axios then below is my code which is not working

```
handleClick(userid){
  axios.get(
    "http://localhost:4000/user/"+userid+"/items.json")
    .then(function (response) {
      dispatch(this.buildhtml.bind(response))
    })
}


  buildhtml(response){
  console.log("m called")
  }
```

buildhtml function is not executing !! any idea

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your code is not working working because your `this` would be undefined with the current implementation you have.

Can you try this?

```
handleClick(userid){
  var self=this;
  axios.get(
    "http://localhost:4000/user/"+userid+"/items.json")
    .then(function (response) {
      self.buildhtml.bind(response) // would work
      dispatch(self.buildhtml.bind(response)) //wont work
    })
}

  buildhtml(response){
  console.log("m called")
  }
```

Now i see above wont work too, even though you change it to self. You are trying to using dispatch. In dispatch you need to pass an **action.** . Reducers take state and action as parameters and they update state based on what action is passed.

Now an action may return an object or a function. Please go through concepts of [redux](http://redux.js.org/) once. This is not the way an action should be dispatched

Comment: can you share your component once? Create a fiddle and share the link?

Comment: checking it ..can you show me what your api call returns?

Comment: it return something like this `{"items":{"12":{"id":12,"title":"guitar qqq","description":"qqqguitar description","created_at":"2016-08-09T13:34:09.000Z","updated_at":"2016-09-07T10:34:50.000Z","user_profile_id":1,"catagory_id":1,"price":null,"images":{"18":"/system/item/18/medium/item2.jpeg?1470749649","19":"/system/item/19/medium/guitar2.jpeg?1470749649","20":"/system/item/20/medium/guitar3.png?1470749649",`

Answer (score 6):

When using [Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/) with [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) ,I too had this Issue but , this is how I solved it.

```
let vue = new Vue({
 el:#<element>,
 methods:{

  method1()
  {
 axios.post('<url>',{<data>})
 .then( ( res ) => {
  this.method2(res)  // method call to method2 
  } )
 .catch( ( err ) => { <call> } );     
  },//method1 end

method2(res){
// statements
} 

}
});
```

Refer [this](http://2ality.com/2014/05/this.html).

Comment: This works. I want to know why this is not working: